# Unable to login by using $this->Auth->login(). (Cakephp)

Tags: php, cakephp

i am trying to login to my admin panel by using $this->Auth->login(), but it always returns false, i have tried as much as i can, now i need your help to sort out this problem, here is my code from controller file:

```
class BrownieController extends BrownieAppController {
public $uses = array('User');

    public function login() {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($this->request->data);
            echo "</pre>";
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            if($this->request->isPost()) {
                $this->Auth->flash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
            }
        }

    }
```

**On print_r the data, it shows:**

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [email] => admin@xin.com
            [password] => admin@123
        )

)
```

which is the exact info stored in users table in my database.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use debug($arr) instead of <pre> + var_dump

Comment: Your password is unhashed in the database? Cake assumes passwords are hashed!

Answer (score 2):

Should have been 'username' instead of 'email' in the request data unless you have changed the configurations

Answer (score 1):

**Reason 1:**

`$this->Auth->login` takes data in the form of

```
array(
    'User'=>array(
        'username'=>'myusername',
        'password'=>'mypassword'
    )
)
```

**Reason 2:**

You must send the password exactly as it appears in the database.

EVERYTHING BELOW THIS LINE IS POSSIBLE BUT NOT LIKELY IN THIS CASE:

Are you sure that when you originally created the username and password, the hashes were setup?

1. To check that your hashes match look at your users table with phpmyadmin or mysql workbench and find the password field for the user chris22
2. Compare that entry to your current hashing. To check your current hash, put the code below somewhere in a controller function (index) and navigate there.

   ```
   debug(Security::hash('stuff'));
   exit;
   ```

Also you can see the [cakephp for login and logout docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout).

I hope this helps!

Comment: `AuthComponent::login()` _can_ take arguments, however this should _only ever_ be used if you want to manually login in a user with arbitrary data! **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#identifying-users-and-logging-them-in**